# Large number of files missing in fileManager of a website deployed on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I am unsure if this is happening by design, or it's supposed to work this way. Through Visual studio Publish option, I published my ASP.NET Core website on Azure App Service. Now, when I access the fileManager on https://mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/fileManager, I am missing majority of the files. I can only browse some log files, several zipped packages.

The website itself works fine when I am trying to access it on the link, however I am unable to browse all the files for it. I was wondering if this is an intended design, or I have done something wrong.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Are you using Kudu or App Service Editor for finding files in https://mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/fileManager ? or default https://mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/ ? and you find files via google browser or edge?

Comment: I am using Kudu here. I can't find the files on both chrome or edge.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 component, that allows web pages to store named key value pairs locally. It just setting to store our web app.

To solve the files not able to view via kudu

Open Browser -> go to Developer tools or hit F12 -> In the console run the following cmd

```
window.localStorage['maxViewItems'] = 1000
```

[image]

Still you are facing issue please check  and compare with Azure App Service Editor and Kudu files. I had checked both Kudu and App Service Editor shows the same files which contain the web app.

Refer [Kudu error with maxViewItems in localstorage](https://www.poppastring.com/blog/kudu-error-with-maxviewitems-in-localstorage)